# Adjusting the color coding on a barplot so that all values are color coded correctly in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a barplot that plots Rates by State and by Category (there are 5 categories) but the problem is that some States have more categories than other states.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({"state" : ["AL","AL","AL","AK", ],
                   "status" : ["Booked", "Rejected","Cancelled","Rejected"],
                   "0" : [1.5,2.5,3.5,1.0]})

df2 = df.groupby(['state','status']).size()/df.groupby(['state']).size()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlabel('State')
plt.ylabel('Bookings')

my_colors = 'gyr'
df2.plot(kind='bar', color=my_colors, orientation='vertical')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This does a good job with most of what I need to do however, what happens is that because some States do not have all values for `status` and hence do not appear in the plot, it makes some of the color coding incorrect because the colors are just shifted to repeat every 5 colors rather then based on whenever a value is missing or not. What can I do about this?

Comment: [Is this really a problem of `Sales_Applications_breakout_percent_after`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? I am not sure how to show an example of the output I expect to see because its a barplot

Comment: I'm asking you to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: right, but how can I show the barplot that I currently have? I don't believe there is a way I can import a png file?

Comment: If you provide a [mcve], everyone can run the code for himself and produce the graphics on his own screen. (You may still add a png if you want, but that is optional, I'd say)

Comment: ok I just made an update, hopefully that is helpful

Comment: It seems all states have an application status. I edited your code to be a [mcve]. But I don't quite see the issue. [Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPGbz.png) how the plot looks like. Not sure what would be desired instead.

Comment: the issue is what I described in the explanation. I set it to 5 colors (it can be any other number, it does not matter) but for certain States, there are applications that have 0. For instance, AK above only has booked but not rejected, so it does not appear in the dataset. What this causes is that a color gets shifted when its say supposed to represent Booked, it actually ends up representing say Rejected because its the 3rd one in line not because that is actually what it is

Comment: Feel free to edit the example to show the issue.

Comment: ok so I made some small change that I hope can help explain what I mean. Right now the 4th element is Rejected and we have 3 colors set up since the 4th element comes along it restarts the set of 3 colors with the green in order. However, because it is Rejected, it is not supposed to be green but should be red instead. There is no association between the color and the Application_Status. In this example you can see that AK only got  Rejected and no Booked or Cancelled causing this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you want to show the data in a grouped fashion, namely to have 3 categories per group, such that each category has its own color.

In this case it seems this can easily be achieved by unstacking the multi-index dataframe,

```
df2.unstack().plot(...)
```

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({"state" : ["AL","AL","AL","AK", ],
                   "status" : ["Booked", "Rejected","Cancelled","Rejected"],
                   "0" : [1.5,2.5,3.5,1.0]})

df2 = df.groupby(['state','status']).size()/df.groupby(['state']).size()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlabel('State')
plt.ylabel('Bookings')

my_colors = 'gyr'
df2.unstack().plot(kind='bar', color=my_colors, orientation='vertical', ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to read up on stacking/unstacking since that seemed to be most critical here and not sure if I fully follow. Is what unstacking accomplishing here is basically kind of like reverse reset_index in some sense that it basically groups by the columns by my 2nd group by Status rather then the State?

Comment: unstack is some kind of pivoting operation. It creates as many columns as you have unique items in your status column, i.e. each possible status gets its own column. Pandas will plots different columns in the grouped fashion as seen in the graph.

Comment: right, but more specifically, hypothetically let's say I would have grouped by 5 different columns in my dataframe, the unstacking would then group/color code it in what way? Like if I were to say groupby State, City, Status, substatus and used unstack on my code, how would it be color coded?

Comment: uhh, I don't know what unstack would do on a multi-index with more than 2 levels from the top of my head. For plotting in the grouped fashion from this answer at least more than 2 indices would not make sense.

Comment: yea, from a practical point of view it probably wouldn't, I just want to make sure I have the unstack concept down

Comment: Since the pandas documentation is not really helpful on that point, why not try it out. That's anyway the best way of learning.

Comment: That's true. You are a python/pandas genius, I was looking at how to do a few other things in Pandas and I see your name everywhere:)